# Convert object to array with Lodash _.map and use map function in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, lodash

I encountered an issue when I used `map` function in React to iterate data because the data is object. So I tried to use `_.map` function of Lodash to convert from object to array. Then I want to iterate the data using `map`function.

It didn't work as I had expected and I'm wondering what is the problem.

Should it be working? It is a ok to use `_.map` to iterate in React?

The data structure 
[image]

The code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { addData } from "../actions/index";
import _ from "lodash";

class List extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.addData()
    }
    render(){
        let item;
        if(this.props.data) {
          item = _.map(this.props.data, data => {

         return (
             <li key={data.id}>
             {data.title}
             </li>
         /* this returns empty data. Only bullet button appears.
         In console, it says [Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.]
         Even though I added a key value. */
         )
     })
    }   


return(
    <div>{item}</div>
)
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
    data : state.data
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {addData})(Search);
```

**UPDATE:**

To debug, did a `console.log(this.props.data)`, which produced this output:

```
Object { data: Array[100] }
```

Comment: Are you getting the data from an API?

Comment: yes. using Fetch in Redux. api address is this one https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts.

Comment: Are you waiting for the API call to finish before rendering the component?

Comment: I use `redux thunk` to get data asynchronously.

Comment: "I encountered an issue when I used map function in React to iterate data because the data is object". The data structure you posted is an array.

Comment: @RickJolly I thought so but when I used 'map' function, I got an error `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.data.map is not a function`. This is an error when I use object to iterate through object not array, I guess.

Comment: Can you show me the `console.log(this.props.data)`? If it is an object, you can use `Object.keys(this.props.data).map(...` or `Object.values` or `Object.entries`.

Comment: Do you have React Developer Tools installed? You should use that or `console.log` to look at what is assigned to `this.props.data`, because it looks like its not what you're expecting. My guess is that in your `mapStateToProps`, `state.data` is not the correct way to select the fetched and stored data.

Comment: @bitstrider console.log inside render returns `Object { data: Array[100] }`. So I guess that data is passed correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `console.log(this.props.data)` output, we can see that value assigned to `this.props.data` is:

```js
{ data : [ /* fetched objects... */ ] }
```

That array you're trying to call `map` on is a level deeper than you expected, so indeed it looks like you're not correctly selecting the fetched and stored data in your `mapStateToProps`.

Try this instead:

```js
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    data : state.data.data
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right and it worked! Thank you so much. when I have a similar problem from next time, I will try this way.